# Quick question about auto-generated code via core data

Tags: iphone, ios

I have two entities Company and Employees. Company has a 1-to-many relationship with employees. An almost exact question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849326/auto-generated-code-for-inverse-1-to-many-relationship-in-core-data-model) however it doesnt answer my question :(. Like in that question, xcode in Company.m generates 4 almost exactly the same methods. However, the prototypes are not included in Company.h which leads me to believe that this is either

- An error and that company.h requires the 4 prototypes for the void functions described in.
- Intended and those 4 methods are only usable in the .m file? If so how to add many employees to a company.

Standing by for any clarifications. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I just set the company on the employee when creating the employees.

```
[newEmployee setValue:company forValue:@"company"];
```

this will trigger the relationship both ways and add the employee to the companies set of employees.

or since you've subclassed it.

```
newEmployee.company = company;
```

Comment: i see. interesting. seems like a good workaround. but its bugging me. what about the 4 auto generated methods that appear when i import the data from the core data model. The link in my question shows 4 methods being generated in the .m file. Are there supposed to be function prototypes for those 4 methods in the header file?

Comment: I've never seen them generated in the header, I've never seen a use case where I wanted to update the entire set of the relationship at once. I think its probably meant for use by other methods in the implementation side of your class.